# mvc with node/express and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm getting confused. All the tutorials I see with mySql end up with something like this:

in models/dbconnection.js

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
port = process.env.PORT || 3333;

if (port == 3333) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'nameDataBase',
        insecureAuth: true
    });
} else {
    console.log("Error");
}

connection.connect();
module.exports = connection;
```

And then in routes/user.js

```
...    

router.delete("/:id", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
        const newLocal = "DELETE FROM login_user WHERE id = ?";
        connection.query(newLocal, [req.params.id], (err,rows,fields) => {
            if (err) {
                res.sendStatus(500);
                return;
            }
            console.log(rows.affectedRows);
            res.status(200).send({delete: rows});
        });

});

module.exports = router;
```

model and controller aren't getting mixed here? If tomorrow I want to change the type of database, I have to make changes in the model and in the routes. Shouldn't I make functions such as `getAllUsersBlaBla(params)` in something like `models/user.js` and then call it from `routes/user.js` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. There shouldn't be any database queries in the router, which is considered part of the controller in MVC.

The model should provide wrapper functions around database queries that can be called from the controller.

A lot of node apps (and probably tutorials) will choose simplicity rather than modularity, that's why you would see code like that.